# Creating campaigns in SFSC automatically creates data extension in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration, marketing-cloud-connect, campaign

I am sending campaigns through salesforce, and suddenly all campaigns send from SF, its started creating a new data extension In Marketing cloud, can you please help me in finding out the reason and how to stop this action ? regards Adity

Comment: You're sending to CRM Campaigns through Marketing Cloud? This is expected behaviour. A data extension's created in the Data Extension root folder that stays there for seven days. The same goes for sending to CRM Reports.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I am sending campaigns from salesforce from past 2 years and there was no automatic data extension created in Marketing cloud before. There is sudden changes past week without ant changes or may be some default action . I am looking to undo this action. Any help will be appreciated. Br